# Javascript toolkit recommendations for Blackberry OS 4.6+

Tags: javascript, blackberry, xui

I'm looking for javascipt toolkit for Blackberry OS 4.6 and above (but must be  4.6 comptible!)  for business applications.  XUI looks interesting but can'y find examples or more than 1 page of documentation.  Anyone have experience/examples with XUI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i do have some experience and xui 2.0 has blackberry OS 4.6 support.

Example:

```
x$(window).on('load', function() { 
    x$('#button').click(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```